# Pattern Rule and VPATH, makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Trying to practice a bit because I need to write a makefile later.
I have the followings Folder structures

```
./Folder1/header1.h
./Folder1/src1.c
./Folder2/header2.h
./Folder2/src2.c
main.c
Makefile
```

The code of each file is the following

header1.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_1();
```

header2.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_1();
```

src1.c

```
#include <header1.h>

void print_1() {
   printf("This is function1\n");
}
```

src2.c

```
#include <header2.h>

void print_2() {
   printf("This is function2\n");
}
```

main.c

```
#include <header1.h>
#include <header2.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   print_1();
   print_2();
   return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
VPATH=./Folder1:./Folder2
OUT_FILE=test

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

all : %.o
```

The idea would have been, for the moment, let generate object files using the VPATH variable. The rule `%.o : %.c` should tell, for each source file generate the object file (they should returned in the same level of the Makefile and main.c).

The second rule should has a prerequisite the object files, so it should call the first rule.

However it doesn't work, why?

(it's been a while since my last makefile).

Comment: `CC=g++` looks odd. `CC` is for compiling C (which your code is), `g++` is for C++.

Comment: As you can probably understand, that makefile is a scratch...Let me change it.

Comment: Sure, but it's still wrong.

Comment: `#include <header1.h>` etc. invokes Undefined Behaviour.

You probably meant `#include "header1.h"` etc.

Comment: I can fix it using the <code>-I</code> flag, but if it makes thing easier I can change it.

Comment: And by the way... that's not the problem.

Comment: @mlp What?! The behaviour is *very* well defined.

Comment: Using `<` `>` around a header name not specified in the Standard invokes UB, @Biffen

Comment: @mlp Have you got a source for that?

Comment: @Biffen: **6.10.2** p2 says the _h-char-sequence_ identifies "a header", as distinct from p3 which says the _q-char-sequence_ identifies "a source file". **6.4.7** says both are _header-name_s but p2 keeps the distinction between "header" and "source file". **7.1.2** p3 talks about "a file with the same name as one of the above" but does not mention other names. Therefore, **Undefined Behaviour**.

Comment: @mlp I don't read it that way. Sure, how files are found is *implementation-defined*, and the paragraphs use different words (‘header’ and ‘source file’), but they essentially *do* the same thing. And sure, the compiler (well, the preprocessor) can have different behaviours for the two, but in the end I fail to understand how you reach the conclusion that it would be *undefined* behaviour. Oh, and §7.1.2 says ‘*the same name **as one of the above***‘, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Biffen "the paragraphs use different words" because the things are different - if they were the same, they would use the same words. An implementation is permitted to, for example, **just know** the contents of the Standard Headers and have no files for them at all. I reach the conclusion that it's UB because nowhere does the Standard define what the behaviour is to be.

Comment: @mlp I strongly disagree but have no mind to continue this argument. Good day.

Comment: Oh, and if you read what I wrote I made the same point about **7.1.2** as you do: the header names `<header1.h>` and `<header1.h>` are not listed, so they are not covered under p2's explicit statement of UB; but since they don't match any of the other clauses of the Standard they are covered as _implicit_ UB per **3.4.3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `all` depend on `%.o` -- percents are for pattern rules, and all is not a pattern rule.  You want something like this:

```
CC=gcc
DIRS=Folder1 Folder2
CFILES=$(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OFILES=$(CFILES:.c=.o)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

all : $(OFILES)
```

`CFILES` will contain the c files in the directories, `OFILES` will be a list of .o files to generate.  The pattern rule will be smart enough to fill in the directory names.

Comment: It's not a patter rule because the % is not in the target, right?

Comment: Also why didn't u used VPATH?

Comment: And what the line OFILES=$(CFILES:.c=.o) does?

Comment: Also I've just tried your makefile, and it returns "make all is up to date".

Comment: Sorry I made a silly mistake. I have one last question. Your make file produce the object files in the same folder as the source files, i.e. src1.o is  returned in the same folder of src1.c, how can I change the makefile you proposed to put all the object files in one specific directory? Assuming a thing like this make sense.

Comment: This can be done by removing the directory names  like so: `$(OFILES) = $(notdir $(CFILES))`, and then using `VPATH` to tell make where to find the .c files.    A word of warning though, this is not good practice.  The problem is if you have ever get two .c files with the same name, it generates some time consuming bugs.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, but isn't sufficient by itself, because the VPATH variable only affects make, not the compiler.  Your #include statements in the .c files will need to be modified to tell the compiler where to find the header files.

```
CC=cc
VPATH=./Folder1:./Folder2
OUT_FILE=test

all : main

%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $<

main : src1.o src2.o main.o
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: This will not work.   `*.o:*.c` will not do what you think it does.   It will get a list of all existing .o files (in the current directory), and make them dependent on all the the .c files (so foo.o would be dependent on _all_ the .c files in the home directory, not just foo.c -- and if foo.o doesn't exist, it won't make a dependency of it.

Comment: But it does work, exactly as shown, at least on Linux using GNU Make 3.81.